# OpenCart - Create sitemap.xml on the fly (each time) or save it to disk and cache it?

Tags: xml, opencart, sitemap.xml

I run an e-Shop with **OpenCart v.1.5.6.5_rc**.

I use OpenCart's: Extensions -> Product Feeds -> sitemap.xml

The e-Shop has about **1500 products** and **80 categories**.
New products are added **once a day** and sometimes **once every two or three days**.

Is it a good practice to generate **sitemap.xml** on the fly every time is needed or it would be better to create it once a day (with schedule) and cache it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The link to `www.yoursite.com/sitemap.xml` actually generates a sitemap in realtime. The `sitemap.xml` file does not exist and is simply rewritten via a `.htaccess` rewrite rule to the feed. Here's the line

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't see how this is going to help me decide if it is better to generate a sitemap in real time or once a day (with schedule) and cache it.

Comment: @kanenas.net sorry, thought you were asking how to create a realtime sitemap

Comment: no problem :) I could really use your experience on this! What would you suggest?

Comment: It really depends on your site performance and traffic. If you're on a shared host you would probably be best to cache the content, however if you have a great server that copes well then the regular sitemap should work just fine

Comment: Unfortunately I am on a shared host :(

Comment: I would highly recommend you consider paying a little extra a month and getting a VPS, as a shared host is not really recommended for any e-commerce store - due to security risks

Comment: what specs should a VPS must have based on the details above (1500+ products and 80 categories)?

Comment: I'd say you need at least 1GB memory and a dual core processor, but it depends on a lot of factors. Most hosting companies will give you a grace period where you can get a refund if you're not happy with the server, so you should be OK to test it first. Double check with their support before hand to ensure you can do so

Comment: Jay is there a way to get in touch with you?

Comment: @kanenas.net - at the moment I'm already swamped with consultancy works. If you need advice you would be best posting on the [commercial support forums for OpenCart](http://forum.opencart.com/viewforum.php?f=88)